Reproduce and avoid RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
I'm getting the error "RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" in a low percent comparing with total number of request per day...however I still cannot reproduce this error...
Can someone help me, please?
I've searched around and gt to reprocude it using sockets (following this link https://www.mastertheboss.com/java/how-to-solve-the-error-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset/)
but I can't reproduce it with resteasy-client..
EDIT
I managed to reproduce the error with this classes:
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int PORT = 8080;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server listening on port " + PORT);

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + clientSocket.getPort());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                clientSocket.setSoLinger(true, 0);
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ResteasyClientBuilderImpl;

public class RestEasyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080");
        target.request().get();
    }
}

I guess there's no way to avoid this error to happen...
after RestEasy's "automatic retries"
if the error remains I guess there's nothing to do but, to investigate the close cause in server side using tools such tcpdump, wireshark, etc

This is way too broad to even guess an answer for this, without your code, one can only grasp at straws here. You should probably let Wireshark run and examine the traffic to the socket, maybe you get your answer in there.
